# Accumulate multiple lists and return the response

Tags: python

I'd love to get feedback on how to write this in a more expressive way.
It works, but style-wise it's not especially thrilling in my opinion. I'm inserting into three lists (`all_results`, `all_titles` and `all_field_order`). Seems kind of cumbersome, but I can't quite wrap my mind around how to write this piece cleaner.

Context: This code I'm showing here is part of a web application where users can reserve specific rooms. It's the view for a form.
It is possible to export reservations between dates. This eventually generates an Excel file. I've implemented the form where the date range can be specified. So far, pretty standard stuff.

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome!

```py
def view_export_all(self, request, form, layout=None):
   self.title = _("Export All")
   layout = layout or ResourceLayout(self, request)
   layout.editbar_links = None

   if form.submitted(request):

       default_group = request.translate(_("General"))

       resources = query_internal_resources()
       ext_resources = query_external_resources()

       grouped = combine_grouped(resources, ext_resources,
                                 sort=lambda x: x.title)

       all_results = []
       all_titles = []
       all_field_order = []

       for entries in grouped.values():
           for resource in entries:
               resource.bind_to_libres_context(request.app.libres_context)
               
                # run_export handles date range and formatting
               field_order, results = run_export(resource=resource,
                                                 start=form.data['start'],
                                                 end=form.data['end'],
                                                 nested=form.format == 'json',
                                                 formatter=layout.
                                                 export_formatter(
                                                     form.format))

               if results:
                   all_titles.append(resource.title)
                   all_results.append(results)
                   all_field_order.append(field_order)

       return form.as_multiple_export_response(keys=all_field_order,
                                               results=all_results,
                                               titles=all_titles)

   if request.method == 'GET':
       from datetime import date
       today = date.today()
       tomorrow = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
       form.start.data, form.end.data = today, tomorrow

   return {'layout': layout, 'title': _("Export"), 'form': form,
           'explanation': _("Exports the reservations of all resources in"
                            " a given date range.")}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some `import`s, making it hard for anyone else to run this code.

Comment: I thought this would be impractical, since to be able to run this, one would have to import hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Hundreds of lines of code is certainly not a big deal on this site. But even without them, at the least having enough supporting code (imports, etc.) to run this function would greatly increase the probability of a meaningful review.